# Make particleground as background for a page

Tags: jquery, html, css

Ok, so I'm going to use particleground(https://github.com/jnicol/particleground) as a background for a page.

I've added the particle ground, however, it appears above of all the content of the page.
Somewhat like this :-
[image]

What can I do to have this as background?
Here's a part of the code.

```
<body>

    <?php include 'nav.php'; ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div id="particle">
                    <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                <img src="images/logo.png">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="college_name">
                                IEC  College of Engineering and Technology
                                <br>
                                presents
                            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <br>
                    <div class="row">
    ........
```

Comment: Umm.. what ? Could you explain a bit more, also what you have tried ? I think you just need to close your particle div before the rest of your content, but have NO idea because you've provided nothing to go on..

Comment: @Pogrindis
I want to make particlegroud as background for the entire page. At the moment, it appears above all of the content. So it's like this, first is particleground, and then rest contents. 

I've tried playing with CSS, no luck.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, I wrote the particle id after my content. For example if I had this:

```
<div class="title">
 <p>Title</p>
</div>
<!-- Calling the particle after the content, so it will be behind the content. 
-->
<div id="particles"></div>
```

Also make sure in CSS, you put an id #particles and declare at to be 100% in width and height. For example:

```
#particles {
  width: 100%
  height: 100%
  position: fixed;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give your `div#particle` a fixed position with a 100% width and height. And before your nav include:

CSS

```
#particle {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
 <body>
    <div id="particle"></div>

    <?php include('nav.php'); ?>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $('#particle').particleground({
            dotColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
            lineColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.1)',
            particleRadius: 10,
            density: 5000,
            directionX: 'right',
            directionY: 'down'
    });
})
```

Now, Your `.nav` and `.container-fluid` will sit over the top of your particle ground.

Comment: Now my content is not even visible. The whole area is covered by particlegroud.

Answer (score 0):

you should add the opening tags and closing tags of the particle div like this:

```
<?php include 'nav.php'; ?>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="particle"></div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <img src="images/logo.png">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="college_name">
                            IEC  College of Engineering and Technology
                            <br>
                            presents
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                <div class="row">
........
```

Comment: your position for your particle should be fixed and the content on top of it should have a relative position